# Why does this console log the output the way it does in this scope example?

Tags: javascript, scope

In this example, I fail to see why this function console logs the string "outside" instead of "inside f1."

I would think that the f1 function assigns a local variable called "x" to the string "inside f1", and then upon calling the f1 function, and console logging the variable "x", it would display "inside f1" NOT "outside"; however, as seen in the code:

```
var x = "outside";

var f1 = function(){
   var x = "inside f1";
};
f1();
console.log(x);
//outside
```

Why does it display "outside" and not "inside f1"?

Comment: Because the variable x containing `inside f1` is local to that function only, it doesn’t exist outside.

Comment: _“I would think that the f1 function assigns a local variable called "x" to the string "inside f1"”_ – you are assigning the string value to the variable, not the other way around.

Comment: If you want the "outside" x to change value, you need to do `x = 'inside f1` instead of declaring a local variable.

Answer (score 0):

The `var` keyword will create a new instance of a variable on the current scope. Javascript (as of ES5) only creates new scopes inside functions. If variable `x` exists outside a function and you have the line `var x = 'something'` then you're creating a version of `x` that only exists in that scope. It overrides the `x` in the parent scope. If you leave off the `var` keyword then it will not create a local `x` but instead look for `x` in a parent scope, ultimately creating a variable `x` on the `window` object if none is found.

So:

```
var x = "outside";

var f1 = function(){
   var x = "inside f1";
};
f1();
console.log(x);
//outside
```

And:

```
var x = "outside";

var f1 = function(){
   x = "inside f1";
};
f1();
console.log(x);
//inside f1
```